# Python Json Config 'Extended Interpolation'

Tags: python, json, configparser

I am currently using the Python library configparser:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser, ExtendedInterpolation
```

I find the ExtendedInterpolation very useful because it avoids the risk of having to reenter constants in multiple places.

I now have a requirement to use a Json document as the basis of the configuration as it provides more structure.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

def get_json_config(file):
    """Load Json into OrderedDict from file"""

    with open(file) as json_data:
        d = json.load(json_data, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

    return d
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to the best way to implement configparser style ExtendedInterpolation?

For example if a node in the Json contains the value ${home_dir}/lumberjack this would copy root node home_dir and take value 'lumberjack'?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `string.Template`. But I'm not sure whether it's your need. There is one package can do this may be. Bellow is what i should do.

`config.json`

```
{
    "home_dir": "/home/joey",
    "class_path": "/user/local/bin",
    "dir_one": "${home_dir}/dir_one", 
    "dir_two": "${home_dir}/dir_two", 

    "sep_path_list": [
        "${class_path}/python",
        "${class_path}/ruby",
        "${class_path}/php"
    ]
}
```

python code:

```
import json
from string import Template

with open("config.json", "r") as config_file:
    config_content = config_file.read()
    config_template = Template(config_content)
    mid_json = json.loads(config_content)
    config = config_template.safe_substitute(mid_json)

    print config
```

This can substitute the defined key in json file.

Comment: But you'll unable to substitute `${parent.child}` paths

Comment: In addition, this will not work with deep interpolation. (i.e., `{ "a": "5", "b": "${a}", "c": "${b}" }`)

Answer (score 0):

Came in very useful; however, I found "config" is a unicode string; I resolved with:

```
# proper code
return json.loads(config)
```